# PHP Dropdown Menus

Tags: php

I want to know if it is possible in PHP to have multiple dropdowns but when you press submit it checks which one has been changed.

Is it possible?

Comment: I've never heard of dropdown menus for PHP

Comment: PHP does not have drop-down menus. PHP is a server-side programming language. I suspect you are looking for an HTML/CSS and (maybe) JavaScript solution. Either way, this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, as the only possible answer to the question you've asked (assuming you mean HTML/CSS/JS) is "Yes, it is possible".

Comment: http://www.coremediadesign.co.uk/learn_web_design/free_web_design_tutorials/tutorial/array_drop_down_menu_php.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Javascript and a hidden field:

HTML:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="1">
....
</select>
<select class="dropdown" id="2">
....
</select>
<input type="hidden" class="dropdownValue" name="dropdownValue" />
```

JS (assuming jQuery):

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
    $('.dropdownValue').val($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a webform and want to check which controls have been changed after submit, I would include on the form hidden fields containing the original values of the controls you want to check, something like:

```
<select id="field1">
<option>one</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="field1-original" value="original value"/>
```

Then after submit, check $_POST and compare the value of field1 with field1-original.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, PHP : PHP Hypertext Protocol, it's just a server-side language, not as JavaScript wich is server-side AND user-side language.

You could do you'r dropdown menu easyli with jQuery  >> http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/